# C++ Struct "Foo Does not name a type" error

Tags: c++, types, struct

Let's say I have:

header.h:

```
struct foo{
    int bar;
};
```

header.cpp:

```
foo foobar;
foobar.bar=1;
```

When compiling this, it tells me at:

```
foobar.bar=1;
```

that foobar does not name a type.

This is true for any combination I have tried of placing the struct and foobar in the .h and .cpp files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you include `header.h` in `header.cpp`?

Comment: Please show some minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Post your whole code. Theoretically it should not give you an error.

Comment: @armanali: That would be an excess of 1k lines of code. Its a text game im making while I learn c++

Comment: @AnOptionalName, Then it's not minimal code. I can reproduce this in [two lines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5046721d50c13754).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While declarations can go outside of functions (although globals are bad practice), other statements need to go in functions, such as `main`:

```
int main() {
    foo foobar;
    foobar.bar=1;
}
```

Comment: Well, I feel stupid. Thanks though, you saved me a lot of hunting/time. It's surprising the things Google _won't_ show in results